# Smallest twin-prime of the form $k \cdot 11699$#$\pm 1$?

Tags: number-theory, twin-primes, primorial

Denote $p$#$:=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots p$

> What is the smallest twin-prime of the form $k\cdot 11699$#$\pm 1$ , where $k$ is a positive integer ?

Sieving out the candidates with Newpgen and checking with PFGW , I found no $k\le 10^5$ doing the job. How large can the smallest $k$ be expected ?

Comment: Sorry for a silly question. Why do you need it?

Comment: You seem to be assuming the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: Seems that $$\large \color\red {k=919\ 988}$$ gives a twin-prime-pair.